# html tags overlap each other on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am very new in html-css. I am coding a website like a simple portfolio. I have nav, 3-sections and footer. I write a responsive html css code. No problem in responsive when I try small size on my pc. But html tags overlap when I try on my mobile Android phone. I try on Google Chrome, Samsuns internet browser, 1 another browser. Same error for each web browsers on mobile. I download a web ide app for mobile. I try on here but same error. How can I solve this problem.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
}

body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 18px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 16px;
}

h3 {
  font-size: 14px;
}

h4 {
  font-size: 12px;
}

h5 {
  font-size: 10px;
}

p {
  font-size: 15px;
}


/*header başlangıç*/

header {
  display: flex;
  padding: 20px;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

header>div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

header>div>img {
  border-radius: 100px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

.close-nav,
.open-nav {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
}

nav {
  display: flex;
}

nav>ul {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav a {
  margin: 10px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .open-nav {
    display: flex;
  }
  .nav {
    display: flex;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background-color: #2196f3;
    padding: 10px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -100%;
    transition: 0.5s;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50vw;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .nav a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .nav a:hover {
    color: #fff;
  }
  .nav.active {
    right: 0;
    transition: 0.2s;
  }
  .nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
  .close-nav {
    display: flex;
  }
}


/*header bitiş*/


/*main başlangıç*/

.main {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 80px;
  padding-right: 80px;
}

.main-1,
.main-3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
}

.main-1 p {
  margin: 10px;
  margin-left: 0px;
}

.main-2 {
  flex: 1;
}

.main-2>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.main-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-2>div:nth-child(1) {
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.socials img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
}

.main-2 img {
  border-radius: 100px;
  width: 200px;
  height: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.main-2 h2,
h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.main-3>div {
  display: flex;
  margin: 10px;
}

.main-3 img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .main {
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 5px;
  }
}

.socials img:hover {
  scale: 1.2;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.main-2 img:hover {
  scale: 1.2;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.main-3>div:hover {
  scale: 1.1;
  transition: 0.5s;
}


/*main bitiş*/


/* skills başlangıç*/

.skills {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-top: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
}

.skills>div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #bcbcbc;
  height: 2px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.all-items {
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.four-items {
  display: flex;
}

.two-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.item {
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #bcbcbc;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.item:hover {
  background-color: #65a2d4;
  scale: 1.1;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.item>img {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .all-items {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .four-items {
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  .two-item {
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  .item {
    flex-direction: row;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: 2px;
    margin-right: 2px;
  }
  .item>img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }
  .item>h3 {
    font-size: 12px;
  }
}


/* skills bitiş*/


/* articles başlangıç*/

.articles {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.articles>div:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: #bcbcbc;
  height: 2px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.all-articles {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: start;
}

.article-item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.article-item:hover {
  transform: translateY(-5px);
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.article-item>h3 {
  width: 270px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  text-align: start;
}

.article-item>h4 {
  color: #808080;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.article-item img {
  width: 270px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .all-articles {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .article-item img {
    width: 270px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 10px;
  }
}


/* articles bitiş*/


/* footer başlangıç */

footer {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}

footer div {
  display: flex;
}

footer p {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 786px) {
  footer {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
  }
  footer p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
}


/* footer bitiş */
```

```html
<html lang="tr">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Try</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Slab&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <header>
    <div>
      <img src="photos/profile-photo.jpg" alt="">
      <h1>amncal ancaknd</h1>
    </div>
    <img class="open-nav" src="icons/menu.svg" alt="">
    <nav class="nav">
      <img class="close-nav" src="icons/cross.svg" alt="">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="smoothScroll(event, 'main')">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="smoothScroll(event, 'skills')">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="smoothScroll(event, 'articles')">Articles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>


  <section class="main" id="main">

    <div class="main-1">
      <h2>Hello I am Sergio</h2>
      <p>futbolfutbol futbol futbol futbolfutbolfutbol futbol futbol futbol futbol futbolfutbol futbolfutbol futbolfutbolfutbol futbolfutbolfutbolfutbolfutbolfutbol</p>
      <p>ancakancak ancakancakancak ancak ancakancak ancak ancakancakancakancakancak ancakancakancak ancakancakancakancakancak ancak ancak ancak ancak v ancak ancak ancak ancakancak</p>
      <div class="socials">
        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/">
          <img src="socials/linkedin.svg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.gmail.com/">
          <img src="socials/google.svg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.github.com/">
          <img src="socials/github.svg" alt="">
        </a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/">
          <img src="socials/instagram.svg" alt="">
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-2">
      <div>
        <img src="photos/profile-photo.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>ancak ancak</h2>
        <h3>ancak ancakancak ancakancak</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="main-3">
      <div>
        <img src="abilities/electrical.svg" alt="">
        <div>
          <h2>Electrical</h2>
          <p>Elektrik bir alandır kanka ne bileyim messi ronaldo</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="abilities/electonics.svg" alt="">
        <div>
          <h2>Electonics</h2>
          <p>Elektronik bir alandır kanka ne bileyim messi ronaldo</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="abilities/software.svg" alt="">
        <div>
          <h2>Software</h2>
          <p>Software bir alandır kanka ne bileyim messi ronaldo</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </section>


  <section class="skills" id="skills">
    <h2>Skills</h2>
    <div></div>

    <div class="all-items">
      <div class="four-items">
        <div class="two-item">
          <div class="item">
            <img src="skills/solidworks.svg" alt="">
            <h3>Solidworks</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="skills/autocad.svg" alt="">
            <h3>Autocad</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="two-item">
          <div class="item">
            <img src="skills/proteus.png" alt="">
            <h3>Proteus</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="skills/c.svg" alt="">
            <h3>C</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="four-items">
        <div class="two-item">
          <div class="item">
            <img src="skills/flutter.svg" alt="">
            <h3>Flutter</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="skills/dart.svg" alt="">
            <h3>Dart</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="two-item">
          <div class="item">
            <img src="skills/html.svg" alt="">
            <h3>HTML</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
            <img src="skills/css.svg" alt="">
            <h3>CSS</h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>


  <section class="articles" id="articles">
    <h2>Related articles</h2>
    <div></div>

    <div class="all-articles">
      <div class="article-item">
        <img src="article-images/electrical.jpg" alt="">
        <h3>Eletrical alanı ile ilgili makale başlığıdır bu kaç kelime olur belli olmaz ama sınır koyacam.</h3>
        <h4>20 Sept,2023</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="article-item">
        <img src="article-images/electonics.jpg" alt="">
        <h3>Electronics alanı ile ilgili metin başlığıdır ama bellidir?</h3>
        <h4>21 Sept,2023</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="article-item">
        <img src="article-images/software.jpg" alt="">
        <h3>Software alanı ile ilgili yazı titlesidir bu kaç kelime olur belli olmaz.</h3>
        <h4>23 Sept,2023</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>




  <footer>
    <p>© Telif Hakkı 2023, Tüm Hakları Saklıdır | ancak</p>
    <div>
      <p>Privacy policy</p>
      <p>Sitemap</p>
    </div>
  </footer>


  <script src="script.js"></script>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: What does it mean : _But html tags overlap_?

Comment: The reason is because you're using fixed sizes in `px` for some of the elements.

Comment: you can imagine HTML tags are in same z index. one div appears on top of another div and I can't see the bottom div.

Comment: @Timothy But no problem on pc. there is problem only mobile phone. How to solve.

Comment: I can't tell where the problem is supposed to be, by emulating multiple different mobile devices via my browser dev tools with your rendered snippet above.